# Excel delete rows from complete list when deleted from master

Tags: vba, excel

Say I have 2 sheets in my workbook.  One is a master list that has a key column that is displayed only once as well as some other pertinent info.  The other one has multiple items where the key could be listed hundreds of times.

What I want to do is when the row is deleted from the master sheet it deletes all rows that have the same key from the other sheet.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Reg

Comment: How is the row deleted? The entire row is completely removed or the contents of the row are deleted (but row remains)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose there are two worksheets - the first is `master` that has all your unique keys and the second is named `keys`.

Next, assume that data is set up as follows:

```
    **Master**                **Keys**
    A      B                   A      B  
1   ABC1   other info...       ABC1   other info...
2   ABC2   other info...       ABC1   other info...
3   ABC3   other info...       ABC2   other info...
4   ABC4   other info...       ABC2   other info...
5   ABC5   other info...       ABC2   other info...
                               ABC3   other info...
                               ABC4   other info...
```

If you select the key in `master` that you want to delete and run the following code this will delete the selected key from `master` and then loop through `keys` and delete any rows that have the same key:

```
Sub DeleteKeys()
    Dim KeyID As String, KeysLastRow As Long, rw As Long

    KeyID = Selection.Value 
    KeysLastRow = Worksheets("keys").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row //Get last row in `keys` column A

    Selection.EntireRow.Delete //Delete selected key (and row) in `master`

    With Worksheets("keys") //Loop through `keys` deleting all matching keys
        For rw = KeysLastRow To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(rw, 1).Value = KeyID Then
                .Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you get started.